# Is it possible to simplify $a = b\mod(mn)$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I don't think so but can anyone verify that there is no way to technically rearrange this equation so that there is no $\mod(xy)$? I'd like to part the x and y somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\gcd(m, n) = 1$, then $a = b \pmod{mn}$ is equivalent to the system of equations $$\begin{eqnarray}a = b &\pmod{n}\\ a = b &\pmod{m}\end{eqnarray}.$$

One direction of this equivalence of obvious, the other one follows from the chinese remainder theorem. If $m, n$ have a common nontrivial factor, you can't just split up the congruences.

Comment: One more question, is this only possible if and only if the gcd(m,n) = 1 or could it occur otherwise?

Comment: The equivalence only works when $\gcd(m, n) = 1$. If they have a common divisor, the system is equivalent to $a = b \pmod{\frac{nm}{\gcd(m, n)}}$.

Comment: ok so only if $\frac{nm}{gcd(m,n)} = 0 \mod(n)$ (and m). Sorry, very rushed it may be incorrect

Comment: No, $n \frac{m}{\gcd(m, n)} = 0 \pmod{n}$ is always correct. You can split up the congruence iff $\gcd(m, n) = 1$.

Comment: i'm a bit new to this and am not quite sure, surely like 25 = 1 mod(24) and also 25 = 1 mod(6) and 25 = 1 mod(4). I hope i'm not getting this notation wrong

Comment: This is correct, but observe that $12 = 0 \pmod{6}$ and $12 = 0 \pmod{4}$, but $12 \neq 0 \pmod{24}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27323/discussion-between-gebra-and-dominik).

Comment: having looked at this again i'm not quite sure what you mean exactly. Could you send a link to a page that shows this?

Comment: As already mentioned, this is the [chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)

Answer (score 0):

The equation is equivalent to $a=b+mnr$ for some integer $r$. You can rearrange that in any of the usual ways, or cancel common factors.